# find closest values c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, k-means

I have read from file a data set of RGB values, I am trying to code K means algorithm so I need to find the closest values in the data set to three numbers (3 values), can any of you help me in showing me how to do this?

I am noob to programming so please be gentle with the abuse :L

Thank you for your time

This code below reads in the file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>;
#include <fstream>;
#include <string>;
#include <cstdlib>;

using namespace std; 

class rgb {

public: 

    int r; 
    int g;
    int b; 

};



int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    char filename[2000]; 

    ifstream infile; 
    infile.open("file.txt"); 

    if (infile.fail()) {

        cerr << "something went wrong :(" << endl; 
        system("pause");
        exit(1); 

    }

    rgb array[500];

    cout << "reading in file: " << endl; 

    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        infile >> array[i].r >> array[i].g >> array[i].b;

        cout << "r: " << array[i].r << "    "; 
        cout << "g: " << array[i].g << "    "; 
        cout << "b: " << array[i].b << "    " << endl; 
    }
```

Then this code finds the closest value in the dataset to centroid one (value1), but read on and you will see what i really need at the bottom, This code was a practice there are probably better ways of doing it :L

```
    int num = 180; // random value assigned at 180
    int centroid1x; 
    int distance = 400;
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {


        if (abs(num - array[i].r) <= distance)
        {
            distance = abs(num - array[i].r);
            centroid1x = array[i].r;
        }


        cout << centroid1x << "    " ; 

    }
    cout << endl << endl; 

    int centroid1y;
    distance = 400;
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {


        if (abs(num - array[i].g) <= distance)
        {
            distance = abs(num - array[i].g);
            centroid1y = array[i].g;
        }

        cout << centroid1y << "    " ;

    }
    cout << endl << endl; 

    int centroid1z;
    distance = 400;
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {


        if (abs(num - array[i].b) <= distance)
        {
            distance = abs(num - array[i].b);
            centroid1z = array[i].b;
        }

        cout << centroid1z << "    " ; 

    }
    cout << endl << endl; 

    cout << "The closest x axis of centroid one is: " << centroid1x << endl; 
    cout << "The closest y axis of centroid one is: " << centroid1y << endl; 
    cout << "The closest z axis of centroid one is: " << centroid1z << endl << endl; 

    cout << "The closest point to centroid one is " << centroid1x << "." << centroid1y << "." << centroid1z << endl; 





    system("pause"); 

    return 0;
}
```

What i need is for the code to find all the numbers that are closer to 180, and all the numbers that are closer to 40 and all the numbers that are closer to 100.

Comment: And what's the problem with your code. You are not expected to write all your code here, but to give a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) of your problem.

Comment: I would like to learn a way to make the program find which numbers in the data set (file) are closer to 180, 40 and 100

Comment: Yeah, but you have a code there, what is not working on it? Can you isolate the problematic part in which is not working as expected?

Comment: ahh I see, the code above only finds (one value) the closest value to 180, I need to find all the values that are closer to 180, all the values that are closer to 40 and all the values that are closer to 100. there are 500 values in "file". I need to change the program so it checks through all the values in "file" and save if it is closer to 180, 100 or 40

Comment: You are not very clear, I'm afraid. Are you trying to subdivide your array of RGB values into arrays so that the values in the first array are all "closer" to one centroid than to all other centroids? And what does "closer" mean to you? Are you looking for a spatial distance in RGB space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear and this might not be what you want, but I'll give it a try anyway.

I think you have an array of RBG values and some centroids, maybe three, which are also RGB values. For each RBG value in the array you want to know which centroid is the closest. This will effectively split your array into as many sub-arrays as there are centroids.

You could create separate arrays for each centroid. I've seen that you use C++, albeit with many C idioms. For example, you are using a fixed-size array instead of a `std::vector`.

I've kept my solution close to that. Instead of providing extra arrays, I have extended the `rgb` class so that it takes an integer reference to the closest centroid. The `split` function assigns this value.

The distance between RGB values is measured as a spactial distance, as if the red, green and blue values were x, y, z values in three-dimensional space.

The code below uses a pre-defined array of 12 RGB values and omits reading the list from a file for brevity. The centroids are pure red, green and blue, but they can in theory be anywhere.

```
#include <iostream>

struct rgb {
    int r; 
    int g;
    int b;
    int ref;    // reference index of closest centroid
};

char hexdigit(int x)
{
    if (x < 0) return '?';
    if (x < 10) return '0' + x;
    if (x < 16) return 'a' + x - 10;
    return '?';
}

std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &os, rgb const &x)
{
    return os << '#'
        << hexdigit(x.r / 16) << hexdigit(x.r % 16)
        << hexdigit(x.g / 16) << hexdigit(x.g % 16)
        << hexdigit(x.b / 16) << hexdigit(x.b % 16);
}

void split(rgb pool[], size_t npool, rgb const cent[], size_t ncent)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < npool; i++) {
        rgb *p = pool + i;
        int dmin = 4*255*255;

        for (size_t j = 0; j < ncent; j++) {
            rgb const *c = cent + j;
            int rr = p->r - c->r;
            int gg = p->g - c->g;
            int bb = p->b - c->b;
            int dd = rr*rr + gg*gg + bb*bb;

            if (dd < dmin) {
                p->ref = j;
                dmin = dd;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    rgb data[12] = {
        {106,  92,  69},
        {135,  16, 137},
        {208, 204, 220},
        { 11,  52, 120},
        { 33,  57,  81},
        {196, 199, 192},
        {236, 237,  85},
        { 89,  27, 225},
        {173,  74, 158},
        {220,   2,  66},
        {171, 145, 204},
        {221,  60, 235}
    };

    rgb cent[3] = {
        {255, 0, 0},
        {0, 255, 0},
        {0, 0, 255}
    };

    split(data, 12, cent, 3);

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        std::cout << data[i] << "    " << cent[data[i].ref] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's exellent thank you, I will try and rewrite this so that I can learn it and then implement my version to my code :)